# Return records when subdatasheets values are null

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm pretty new to SQL and am kind of jumping in at the deep end here.

I'm building a tool from scratch in Excel that utilises and Access Database - and whilst the basic Queries aren't causing me any serious issues - the more complex ones are.

I have four tables. Users, Issues, Votes and Comments.

One user can create many issues, one issue can have many votes and one issue can also have many comments.

I want to create a query that shows a list of issues, with the count of vote_id and comment_id for each

I.e. Issue 1 has 3 votes and 4 comments, and so on - however when the item has zero comments or votes, my query is returning nothing at all

```
SELECT 
     users.user_name
,    Count(vote.query_id) AS CountOfquery_id
,    Count(comments.query_id) AS CountOfquery_id1
,    issues.query_id
,    issues.query_raised_by
,    issues.query_raised_date
,    issues.query_summary
,    issues.query_status
,    issues.query_status_date
,    issues.query_detail
,    issues.query_response
,    issues.query_tag1
,    issues.query_tag2
,    issues.query_tag3
,    issues.query_tag4
FROM 
(
    (users INNER JOIN issues 
        ON users.user_id = issues.query_raised_by) 
    INNER JOIN vote 
        ON issues.query_id = vote.query_id) 
    INNER JOIN comments 
        ON issues.query_id = comments.query_id
    GROUP BY 
        users.user_name
        , issues.query_id
        , issues.query_raised_by
        , issues.query_raised_date
        , issues.query_summary
        , issues.query_status
        , issues.query_status_date
        , issues.query_detail
        , issues.query_response
        , issues.query_tag1
        , issues.query_tag2
        , issues.query_tag3
        , issues.query_tag4;
```

Is there an easy way to do this? Am I massively overcomplicating the issue?

Basically I want to populate a table in Excel with a list of issues and the number of votes and comments for each, how can I get count to work?

Comment: Thank you for the edit @Luv :)

Answer (score 0):

Does doing:

```
COUNT(vote.query_id) OVER (PARTITION BY users.user_name)
COUNT(comments.query_id) OVER (PARTITION BY users.user_name)
```

and changing your group statement to say `group by users.user_name` only give you the result you're after?

Comment: I get a missing operator syntax error with the word OVER?

Comment: Ah, just found out Access doesn't support that. Apologies!

Comment: Thank you for trying though, have a great day :)

Comment: What happens if you change your inner join to a left join?

Comment: that worked perfectly, I left the one INNER join and the others worked - I just googled what the different joins do and it makes a lot more sense now. Thank you for taking the time, that Is really helpful! Its difficult to pick up as you go along, I should probably have done some more formal learning.. :)

Comment: Great stuff. I'm still pretty new to SQL as welland still struggle when to use left, inner and outer joins myself.

Answer (score 0):

@Dekks suggested using Left Join instead of Inner Join - I just googled what the different joins do and it makes a lot more sense now.

Just wanted to post an update for you, in case it helps anyone else :)